# Minted "underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph" when using bgcolor

Tags: formatting, minted, code, badness

When I use [minted](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) to highlight BASH code like this

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{vim}
\newminted{bash}{fontfamily=tt, gobble=2, linenos}
\newmint{bash}{}

\begin{document}

AAAA

\begin{bashcode}
  BBBB
  CCCC  
\end{bashcode}

DDDD

 \end{document}
```

it works perfectly. If I add background color using

```
\newminted{bash}{bgcolor=Ivory, fontfamily=tt, gobble=2, linenos}
```

it looks same, but for every code block I get an error like

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
```

Nothing else changes, so that I don't udnerstand why using `bgcolor` option causes the badness to appear.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is just a bug report  without any real minimal example

Comment: @egreg I think it would be better to ask the OP for a minimal example, and then provide an answer saying "This is a bug. You should file a bug report." Closing the question means that others who suffer from the same bug won't know what to do.

Comment: @egreg: I added minimal working backbone. But otherwise I agree, it finally turned to be just bugreport (reported on appropriate place, so I hope it will be fixed soon, at least for openSUSE, I didn't check another Linux distributions). I'm going to close it myself as soon as the forum system allows me to do that. But still someone may face similar problem.

Comment: @Tilia I get *no* underfull box message from your example. You just have an outdated version of `minted` on your system, because you're using the TeX Live provided by OpenSUSE, that lags far behind. If it *was* a bug, it has long be solved: just upgrade your TeX Live with the “vanilla” TUG version, there are instructions on the site about how to do it. As such it's an OpenSUSE bug, so it's off topic for this site.

Comment: @egreg Yes, it is openSUSE bug, but most of its users anyway look for help with TeX Live here... And there might be similar problem in other distributions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is caused by an out-of-date package/program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently bug in older version of `minted` available in [openSUSE repository](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Publishing:/TeXLive/) (I have requested upgrade of the package). After upgrade to version 2.1 directly from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) (respectively [GitHub](https://github.com/gpoore/minted)) the `badness` disappears (without any change in code).

Comment: To see the progress https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=959672

Answer (score 1):

no problem with an up-to-date TeXLive 2015

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{vim}
\newminted{bash}{fontfamily=tt, gobble=2, linenos}
\newmint{bash}{}

\begin{document}

AAAA

\begin{bashcode}
  BBBB
  CCCC  
\end{bashcode}

DDDD

 \end{document}
```